# Aiogram problem with sending forward message

Tags: aiogram

I have the id of the users and the id of the forward messages that I need to send by this user in the bot. This should not be sent to a separate channel, but directly in the bot to the user.

send_forward won't help, because chat_id must be specified there.

send_message won't help because you can't specify a forward message there

Answer (score 0):

You could use chat_id (user id) where you where you want forward message

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).